# When is a good time to thin your seedlings?

Tags: tomatoes, seedlings

First year in a long time starting tomatoes from seed. They're doing very well. When do most people decide to cut down the ones you don't want to continue growing? I know it's a little early at this point.

Answer (score 6):

A lot can happen between now and *then*. I usually wait until there are a few true leaves and it's clear which plants have *taken off*.

Last year, I had one little runt that never grew more than a few inches tall while its neighbors were already a few feet tall, so don't cull *too* early. Some just never get the message that it's time to GROW GROW GROW.